# Creating categorical variable from continuous variable w/ scaled data

Tags: r, categorical-data, continuous

I've lurked in this community for a while but this is my first question...

**Background:**
I'm working with the breast cancer data from UCI. [DATA](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Breast+Cancer+Wisconsin+%28Diagnostic%29)

What I'm trying to do is a Latent Class Analysis (technically Latent Profile as these are continuous variables), but I must first scale my values for each variable.

Once I scale, I now have 32 variables each scaled and ranging from negative to positive (the poLCA function cannot use negatives or zeros I believe). See below for an example of one of my scaled features.

```
> summary(scaled.dat.1)
   V1
```

Min.   :-2.0279
 1st Qu.:-0.6888
 Median :-0.2149
 Mean   : 0.0000
 3rd Qu.: 0.4690
 Max.   : 3.9678

**Question**
How do I change these scaled continuous values to categorical values of say 1:5?

Comment: Have a look at `?cut`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To categorize in 5 groups, I would do something like this...

```
var1 <- c(NA, sample(-20:20, replace = T, size = 50))
thresholds <- quantile(var1, probs = seq(0, 1, length.out = 6)[-1], na.rm = T)
cat.var <- sapply(var1, (function(i){
  ifelse(is.na(i), NA, min(which(i <= thresholds)))
}))
plot(cat.var~var1)
```

If you want to apply this to the whole data frame

```
categorize <- function(var1){
  thresholds <- quantile(var1, probs = seq(0, 1, length.out = 6)[-1], na.rm = T)
  cat.var <- sapply(var1, (function(i){
    ifelse(is.na(i), NA, min(which(i <= thresholds)))
  }))
}
apply(df, 2, categorize)
# alternatively
for (j in 1:ncol(df)) {
  df[,j] <- categorize(df[,j])
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance! If I wanted to loop this through all the variable columns, how would you suggest nesting this in that loop?

Comment: I tried this for loop changing 'var1' to 'j' but I don't believe it worked:


for (j in 1:ncol(dat)) {

  thresholds <- quantile(j, probs = seq(0, 1, length.out = 6)[-1])
  cat.var <- sapply(j, (function(i){
    min(which(i <= thresholds))
}))

}